# How to calculate modulus of large numbers with large prime?

Tags: cryptography, primes, modulus

I am working with elliptic curve cryptography on software environment. I wish to inquire how to efficiently implement the modulo operation of large numbers with respect to a large prime number.
e.g. (192 bit number) mod (192 bit mersenne prime)

If there are any tricks or algorithms you can refer that would be very helpful as I am working with resource constrained sensor nodes.

Comment: Normally, you don't just have an *n*-bit number that you want to apply *mod p* on. The modulo operation has to be integrated into addition, multiplication and exponentiation.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant the binary of 'n' has to be 192 bits long.

Comment: Related questions: [What are the computational benefits of primes close to the power of 2?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/what-are-the-computational-benefits-of-primes-close-to-the-power-of-2) and [How does NaCL Poly1305 implementation do modular multiplication?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9222/how-does-nacl-poly1305-implementation-do-modular-multiplication)

Answer (score 3):

There is no 192-bit [Mersene prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime), as considered in the question.

Implementing modular reduction of a 192-bit integer *x* modulo another 192-bit prime *p* is very straightforward: the result is *x* when *x*<*p*, or *x*-*p* otherwise.

Perhaps the question really is about efficient modular reduction modulo a 192-bit prime *p* of some larger quantity, for a prime *p* as commonly used in Elliptic Curve Cryptography. Such primes are often chosen in a way allowing efficient modular reduction. For example, for P-192, the prime modulus *p* is [specified](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/dss/NISTReCur.pdf#page=6) to be 6277101735386680763835789423207666416083908700390324961279 which is `fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffeffffffffffffffff`<sub>h</sub>
 or 2<sup>192</sup>-2<sup>64</sup>-1. This *p* is so near  (2<sup>32</sup>)<sup>6</sup> that when working in base 2<sup>32</sup>, estimation of a quotient digit in modular reduction modulo *p* is very easy, much like estimating a new digit when performing schoolbook [Euclidian division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) by 999899 in base 10 is easy: much of the time, the leftmost digit of what remains of the dividend is that new digit of the quotient.